# Newly added translation is not shown

Tags: internationalization, translation, typo3

On a Typo3 4.4.2 with existing translations I wanted to add a new one. But the text element is only displayed on the default language and not on the English page. Then I tried to add a content element on the English page. Here it will be shown but only in English. It seems that the translations are completely separated from each other ...

Here is the TS:

```
config {
  linkVars = L
  sys_language_mode = content_fallback
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
  sys_language_uid = 
  language = de
  locale_all = de_DE
  doctype = xhtml_trans
  htmlTag_langKey = de
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
page.config.language = en
page.config.locale_all = en_EN
[global]
```

What is here wrong? Deleting the cache had no success so it is another problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm just guessing: try to set `config.sys_language_uid = 0` in the german setup. Additionally, try to remove `page.` from the english config part.

Comment: @Jost: Thanks for your suggestion. That didn't help. Seems the mapping between the different translations are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the "Copy default content elements" option for translating default content elements to English language.

Comment: You mean the button `Create a copy for translation (english)`?

Comment: Yes. Use "Copy default content elements" option and edit it for english contents.

Comment: I think the button "Copy default content elements" is in the old versions of TYPO3. I can only find the "Create a copy for translation" button. I used this button but the result is the same. I can translate the element but it is never shown on the English page. In the backend everything seems normal. I tried to add a content element only on the English page - then it appears on the website (in the backend only if i choose in the Localization view: english and "Only localized elements"). If I use the translation method the content element doesn't appear.

Comment: Sorry. You're right, it's "Create a copy for translation" button.
Also set 
    config.sys_language_uid = 0
in the above code for default language

Comment: Replace: "config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated"

with


"config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 1,0"

Comment: I tried your `config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 1,0` setting together with `config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated`. Nothing has changed. But my settings should be OK according to this page: http://www.typo3-media.com/blog/article/mehrsprachigkeit-und-templavoila.html (see section "Beispielkonfiguration für eine TemplaVoila Seite")

Comment: Please verify the sys_language_uid of English.

Comment: German: 0, English: 1, Czech: 2, Italian: 3, French: 4, Dutch: 5, Slovenian: 6

Comment: Please go through the "Typoscript Object browser" and "Template Analyser" and check whether we have any syntax errors.

Comment: I looked through but I couldn't find something special (but the highlighting in `Template Analyzer` is strange and in `TS Object browser` the settings are exactly the one I set). Now I created a new page and copied the exact element on this page. Here everything works fine! So what is wrong with the page?

Comment: Please verify that you've closed all the open brackets.
Also it will be better if you move the language configuration typoscript to a new ts template and include it in the root page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to translate the page with the content element too. Otherwise the content element can not be saved.

If the mapping between the translation is lost, then you have to fix this in the database or with the extension `languagevisibility`.